# Create sketch to identify people in a group picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to create a sketch like the numbered ellipses on the right to help identifying people in a group image? Take for example this group picture of the 5th Solvay Conference in 1927

[image]

---

If you want to test the answer on other images, here are some similar ones contributed by @StevenB.Segletes

From the 2nd Solvay Conference in 1913:

[image]

And one from the BRL SAC (1940)

[image]

Incidentally, the world's first computer, the ENIAC, was housed in a wing of the building being built in the background (B328, APG, MD).

Comment: What a bunch of gray matter... +1 just for posting the photo ;-)

Comment: @Rmano If there would be a special kind of gravity for intelligence, there would be a black hole instead of this assembly :)

Comment: I happen to collect those photos.  Yours is from the 1927 conference.  If you like, I could add the 1913 conference photo to your question...(includes many of these, plus Gruneisen, Laue, Thomson, Rutherford, Nernst, Sommerfeld, Wien, et al.)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Nice hobby! Feel free to add it if you think it makes the question clearer. Alternatively I can offer add it as second example to the answer.

Comment: It doesn't make anything clearer, but what is clear is that readers are interested in the photos themselves.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks a lot for your additions!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following example uses a two step approach.

#### First step: Tagging people

One can show the image overlaid by a grid using

```
\tagimage[\linewidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}
```

[image]

This makes it easier to get the coordinates of the people. They are added one by one inside a `\tagpeople{}` macro.

For example to add a people which are continuously numbered:

```
\tagpeople{
    \tagperson{0.060,0.505}
}
```

Or a person with a user defined label:

```
\tagpersonlabel{0.060,0.505}{x}
```

(both of these commands also take optional arguments to shift the position of the label, e.g. `\tagperson[xshift=0.5cm]{0.150,0.485}` or `\tagpersonlabel[yshift=0.5cm]{0.092,0.455}{x}`)

#### Second step: Display tagged image

The numbered ellipses can now be displayed with `\showtags[\linewidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}`

[image]

Or a semi-transparent version of the image overlayed with the ellipses can be shown with `\showtagsimage[\linewidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}`

[image]

> Example image to compile the code: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Solvay_conference_1927.jpg/700px-Solvay_conference_1927.jpg

#### Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
%   showframe=true
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\tikzset{%
    tag ellipse/.style={%
        black!80!white,
        fill=white,
    },
    tag label/.style={%
        black,
    },
}

\newlength{\tagimage@y}
\newcounter{tagimage@count}

\newcommand{\@tagpeople}{}
\newcommand{\tagpeople}[1]{%
    \def\@tagpeople{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\tagpersonlabel}[3][]{%
    \stepcounter{tagimage@count}%
    \draw[tag ellipse] (#2) ellipse [x radius=0.019, y radius=0.038] node[tag label,#1] {#3};%
}

\newcommand{\tagperson}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{tagimage@count}%
    \draw[tag ellipse] (#2) ellipse [x radius=0.019, y radius=0.038] node[tag label,#1] {\thetagimage@count};%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% create debug plot to place the ellipses and labels
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% parameter:
% #1 [optional] image width, default \linewidth
% #2 image name
\newcommand{\tagimage}[2][\linewidth]{%
    \setcounter{tagimage@count}{0}%
    \noindent%
    \settoheight{\tagimage@y}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=#1,y=\tagimage@y]%

        % origional image %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}};

        % grid for positioning %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \draw[help lines,xstep=.025,ystep=.025,gray] (0,0) grid (1,1);
            \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1,white] (0,0) grid (1,1);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {.\x}; }
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {.\y}; }
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

        % ellipses %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \@tagpeople%

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% display just ellipses and tags
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% parameter:
% #1 [optional] image width, default \linewidth
% #2 image name
\newcommand{\showtags}[2][\linewidth]{%
    \noindent%
    \setcounter{tagimage@count}{0}%
    \settoheight{\tagimage@y}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=#1,y=\tagimage@y]%
        \@tagpeople%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% display tags over semi-opaque image
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% parameter:
% #1 [optional] image width, default \linewidth
% #2 image name
% #3 [optional] south west corner of optional clip
% #4 [optional] north east corner of optional clip
\NewDocumentCommand{\showtagsimage}{ O{\linewidth} m O{0,0} O{1,1}}{%
    \noindent%
    \setcounter{tagimage@count}{0}%
    \settoheight{\tagimage@y}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=#1,y=\tagimage@y]%

        % black/white image %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \clip (#3) rectangle (#4);
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}};
        \fill[white,opacity=0.7] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

        % ellipses %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \@tagpeople

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tagpeople{%
%   \tagpersonlabel{0.060,0.505}{1}
%   \tagpersonlabel[yshift=0.5cm]{0.092,0.455}{2}
%   \tagperson[xshift=0.5cm]{0.150,0.485}
    \tagperson{0.060,0.505}
    \tagperson{0.092,0.455}
    \tagperson{0.150,0.485}
    \tagperson{0.169,0.631}
    \tagperson{0.198,0.450}
    \tagperson{0.243,0.599}
    \tagperson{0.252,0.505}
    \tagperson{0.295,0.575}
    \tagperson{0.300,0.455}
    \tagperson{0.365,0.498}
    \tagperson{0.376,0.579}
    \tagperson{0.412,0.445}
    \tagperson{0.469,0.573}
    \tagperson{0.482,0.510}
    \tagperson{0.543,0.458}
    \tagperson{0.544,0.595}
    \tagperson{0.570,0.508}
    \tagperson{0.627,0.589}
    \tagperson{0.635,0.458}
    \tagperson{0.665,0.496}
    \tagperson{0.710,0.591}
    \tagperson{0.718,0.455} 
    \tagperson{0.774,0.495}
    \tagperson{0.779,0.598}
    \tagperson{0.832,0.635}
    \tagperson{0.833,0.449} 
    \tagperson{0.874,0.486}
    \tagperson{0.882,0.596}
    \tagperson{0.913,0.432} 
}%

% debug plot
\tagimage[\linewidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}%

\clearpage

% just the lables
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}

{
\centering
\showtags[\linewidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}

}%

\noindent 1: Debye, 2: Langmuir, 3: Knudsen, 4: Piccard, 5: Planck, 6: Henriot, 7: Bragg, 8: Ehrenfest, 9: Curie, 10: Kramers, 11: Herzen, 12: Lorentz, 13: de Donder, 14: Dirac, 15: Einstein, 16: Schrödinger, 17: Compton, 18: Verschaffelt, 19: Langevin, 20: de Broglie, 21: Pauli, 22: Guye, 23: Born, 24: Heisenberg, 25: Fowler, 26: Wilson, 27: Bohr, 28: Brillouin, 29: Richardson 

\clearpage

% lables and semi-opaque image
\tikzset{%
    tag ellipse/.style={%
        black,
        fill=white,
        opacity=0.5
    },
}
\showtagsimage[\linewidth]{700px-Solvay_conference_1927}%

\noindent 1: Debye, 2: Langmuir, 3: Knudsen, 4: Piccard, 5: Planck, 6: Henriot, 7: Bragg, 8: Ehrenfest, 9: Curie, 10: Kramers, 11: Herzen, 12: Lorentz, 13: de Donder, 14: Dirac, 15: Einstein, 16: Schrödinger, 17: Compton, 18: Verschaffelt, 19: Langevin, 20: de Broglie, 21: Pauli, 22: Guye, 23: Born, 24: Heisenberg, 25: Fowler, 26: Wilson, 27: Bohr, 28: Brillouin, 29: Richardson 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How come that there is not a single duck (nor koala nor marmot) on this picture. (The fact that the Schrödinger equation was discovered on an Alpine hut strongly suggests that he got it from the marmots. ;-)

Comment: @marmot All the ducks, koalas and marmots where probably working hard on new theories while the photo was taken :)

Comment: A hard-working marmot? Never heard of that before. ;-)

Comment: Rest assured, @marmot, no marmots were harmed in the making of that photo.

Comment: isn't `ellipse [x radius=0.019, y radius=0.038]` with he new syntax?

Comment: @touhami Oh, you are right! If I understand the documentation correctly, the old syntax should have the same result, the new syntax is encouraged for readability of the code.

Comment: @touhami I corrected it in the code. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: But how can you be certain about where to put no. 24?

Comment: @Thruston ... as long as I don't make any claims about his momentum this should be fine :)